# Firefox file browser across NFS mount

Tags: linux, nfs, firefox

On `Rhel 7.6` / `firefox 52.8.0`

I'm trying to navigate through my filesystem via the firefox URL using an entry like `file:///tmp`.  Certain directories are showing up with access denied errors.  Most annoyingly, if I try to browse to an NFS mount point I get access denied.

The permissions on the directories look fine.  I created a similar directory parallel to the nfs share mount points as a test.  The example `/mnt` directory looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ # root root # *date* *time* **NFSMountPoint**

drwxr-xr-x. # root root # *date* *time* **DummyDir**
```

where the `NFSMountPoint` directory is just that and the `DummyDir` is one I created with `mkdir` and `chmod`.

Logged in as an unprivileged user I can navigate both of them equally from the command line.  But when that unprivileged user launches firefox and uses `file:///mnt/NFSMountPoint` I get access denied.  However, using `file:///mnt/DummyDir` succeeds.

That isn't the only example I could find.  Using firefox I could browse `/usr` but not `/usr/lib`.  Nor could I browse `/etc`.  Yet, from the command line, again, as the unprivileged user I have no issue listing the files in those directories.

So can anyone suggest a cause for this behavior?

Comment: Does it work with chrome? Also, you need to make sure that the user has access to the mounted folder itself, not the mountpoint. The permissions set on the mountpoint don't matter, they are 'overruled' by the permissions of the mounted folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have apparmor (or selinux) enables? Apparmor has a tool that will show you if it causes a permission denied.

Comment: selinux was the culprit.  setenforce 0 allowed firefox to navigate across the NFS link.  

I checked and the user had full access to the directory structure on the NFS server side as well, to answer user rudib.

Comment: Disabling security at such a granular level is not the way to go. Without security we are not secure.

Comment: It is customary to thank an answerer, by clicking the tick (✓)